# Number of Subfields sandwiched between two fields

Tags: field-theory

Let $\omega$ be a complex cube root of unity such that $\omega \neq 1$. Suppose L is the field $\mathbb Q(2^{1/3},\omega)$ generated by them over the field of rationals. Then, the number of subfields K of L such that $\mathbb{Q} \subset K \subset L$ is 4.

Here it's proper subsets.
My approach was to use Tower theorem but I was getting 2 as the answer. So degree of [L:Q]=8. Hence degree of [K:Q]=2 or 4 (as proper subsets). Hence, K=$\textbf{Q(2^{1/3})}$ or $\omega$

Comment: correct $[L:\Bbb{Q}]=6$ not $8$

Comment: Won't it be 8? See as a basis the elements I have are {$\omega$, $\omega^2$, $2^{1/3}$, $2^{2/3}$, $\omega 2^{1/3}$, $\omega^2 2^{1/3}$, $\omega 2^{2/3}$, $\omega^2 2^{2/3}$}?

Comment: this is not a basis as shows the equation:  $w 2^{\frac{1}{3}}+w^2 2^{\frac{1}{3}}+2^{\frac{1}{3}}=0$ because $w^2+w+1=0$, thanks

Answer (score 3):

the strict subfields are $\Bbb{Q}(w)$, $\Bbb{Q}(^3\sqrt{2})$, $\Bbb{Q}(^3\sqrt{2}\;w)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(^3\sqrt{2}\;\bar{w})$

Comment: What is the method used to derive above, how i can conform it is true